# How to migrate from ide to virtio in RHEL 6.5 KVM guest with LVMs

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, rhel6, virtio, ide

I want to migrate a IDE-using, LVM-based KVM guest running RHEL 6.5. I found this steps in [this page](http://www.grosseosterhues.com/2011/03/migrate-kvm-ide-to-virtio/):

> 1) Run virsh edit . From there, edit the config file and
>   adjust all lines of
>
> `<target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>`
>
> so they look like this
>
> `<target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>`
>
> Furthermore, remove all `<address type .../>` lines so that libvirt can
>   regenerate them appropriately.
>
> 2) Inside the guest, edit /etc/fstab and replace all occurrences of
>   /dev/sdX with /dev/vdX`.
>
> 3) That’s it, now shutdown the machine and start it with an virsh
>   start  (just a reboot inside the started VM won’t work).

Cool, seems easy but it doesn't cover the case with LVMs. Neither in my /etc/fstab nor in my /etc/grub.conf I found any /dev/sdX path that I could change (besides one commented in the grub.conf file). Should I do anything more with the lvms? The disk shown to the VM is a raw LUN comming from a multipathed equallogic SAN.

```
[root@testphys ~]# virsh domblklist aplitest
Target     Source
------------------------------------------------
hda        /dev/eql/vol-so-aplitest
hdc        -
```

VM config file (extract with the disk configuration)

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
  <source dev='/dev/eql/vol-so-aplitest'/>
  <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
</disk>
```

Guest's fdisk -l output for the disk (partition 2 is then used as the physical volume for the lvms shown in fstab below)

```
[root@aplitest ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 118.1 GB, 118122086400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14360 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000fb75

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       14361   114840576   8e  Linux LVM
```

Guest's /etc/fstab

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Fri Feb 28 15:51:07 2014
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/vg_aplitest-lv_root /                  ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=0de4d0fc-3637-4b10-908f-7cde8d9347c2 /boot      ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_aplitest-lv_home /home              ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_aplitest-lv_opt /opt               ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_aplitest-lv_tmp /tmp                ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_aplitest-lv_usr /usr                ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_aplitest-lv_var /var                ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_aplitest-lv_var_log /var/log        ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_aplitest-lv_swap swap               swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

Guest's /etc/grub.conf

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_aplitest-lv_root
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_aplitest-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_aplitest/lv_swap  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=la-latin1 rd_LVM_LV=vg_aplitest/lv_root rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64.img
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux (2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_aplitest-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_aplitest/lv_swap  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=la-latin1 rd_LVM_LV=vg_aplitest/lv_root rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.img
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything else. Go shutdown and start the VM.